# How to match or capture a specific substring-pattern from a given string via regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

How can I cut password from message via regular expression?
And how I can use it in function, because code duplication is not a good idea ?
Now I'm doing it via slice like this:

```
  message.html.body.slice(14,24));
```

message output:

```
  html: MessageContent {
    links: [],
    images: [ [Image] ],
    body: 'Your password 5gIlrjtxDy<img src="some link />'
  },
```

I'm trying to do it like this :

```
const [_, retailerPassword] = retailerMessage.html.body.trim().match(/Your\s+password\s+(\w+)/);
  console.log(retailerPassword);

const [_, recipentPassword] = recipentMessage.html.body.trim().match(/Your\s+password\s+(\w+)/);
  console.log(recipentPassword);
```

But after that I have problem with redeclaring block-scoped variable '_'.
And I tried to do it in function :

```
const extractPassword(text:string):string => {
const [_, password] = `


Your password QfzW4zbHg4

`.trim().match(/Your\s+password\s+(\w+)/);
return password
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's main problem comes from following combination ...

- Using the same destructuring assignment pattern twice via `const` and therefore colliding with the 2nd `_`-assignment.
- The usage of `_` is due to using the password capturing group which is the 2nd entry of the `match` method's result array; thus being forced to somehow contain the 1st entry, which is the regex match, by assigning it to the never to be used `_`-variable.

This easily can be fixed by not using destructuring assignments at all. One simply writes ...

```
const retailerPassword = retailerMessage
  .html.body.trim().match(/Your\s+password\s+(\w+)/)[1];

const recipentPassword = recipentMessage
  .html.body.trim().match(/Your\s+password\s+(\w+)/)[1];
```

**Note**

A more generic and/or language agnostic approach like ... [`/(?<=\s)\w+(?=<img)/`](https://regex101.com/r/jwAf0r/2) or even simpler [`/\S+(?=<img)/`](https://regex101.com/r/jwAf0r/1) ... could try to ...

- match anything which is not a whitespace (for passwords where whitespace is not allowed)
- until the next match will be the character sequence `'<img'` ...

```js
const retailerMessage = {
  html: {
    links: [],
    images: [ [Image] ],
    body: 'Your password 5gIlrjtxDy<img src="some link />',
  }
};

const retailerPassword = retailerMessage
  // // [https://regex101.com/r/jwAf0r/2]
  // .html.body.trim().match(/(?<=\s)\w+(?=<img)/);
  // [https://regex101.com/r/jwAf0r/1]
  .html.body.trim().match(/\S+(?=<img)/)[0];

console.log({ retailerPassword });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

... since the OP did ask for it ...

```js
function getPasswordFromMessage(message) {

  // // [https://regex101.com/r/jwAf0r/2]
  // .html.body.trim().match(/(?<=\s)\w+(?=<img)/);

  // [https://regex101.com/r/jwAf0r/1]
  return message?.html?.body?.trim()?.match(/\S+(?=<img)/)?.[0] ?? null;
}

const retailerMessage = {
  html: {
    links: [],
    images: [],
    body: 'Your password 5gIlrjtxDy<img src="some link />',
  }
};
const recipientMessage = {
  html: {
    links: [],
    images: [],
    body: 'Your password FooBarBIZ<img src="some link />',
  }
};

const retailerPassword = getPasswordFromMessage(retailerMessage);
const recipientPassword = getPasswordFromMessage(recipientMessage);
const failedGetPassword = getPasswordFromMessage({});

console.log({
  retailerPassword,
  recipientPassword,
  failedGetPassword,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: updated my question. how to do it in function? because of code duplication

Comment: @Puzzle234 ... are you asking how one does wrap a `function getPassword(str) { return ...; }` around something like `str.trim().match(/\S+(?=<img)/)` where the function then gets invoked via e.g. `const retailerPassword = getPassword(retailerMessage.html.body)` or `const recipientPassword = getPassword(recipientMessage.html.body)` ?

Comment: @Puzzle234 ... wrapped a function statement around a more fail-safe variant of the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string replace method for that.

Also, the block-scoped variable redeclaration problem might be because you're altering the message object; If so, copying the string should solve the issue.

Like so:

```
const retailerStr = retailerMessage.html.body;
const pass = retailerStr.replace(/Your\s+password\s+(\w+)(.*)/,'$1');
// pass === "5gIlrjtxDy"
```

Comment: updated my question. It's good, but how to do it in function?